# Jsp div order get changed while rendering

Tags: java, html, jsp, jboss, weblogic

In jsp div's are in below order

```
<div id="identification"/>
<div id="address"/>
<div id="communication"/>
<div id="familyDetail"/>
```

but while rendering in JBOSS and Weblogic server below is HTML output

```
<div id="address"/>
<div id="communication"/>
<div id="identification"/>
<div id="familyDetail"/>
```

Jsp java file also in same order as in jsp but while converting in HTML it gets changed

Comment: Could you specify exact JBoss and Weblogic versions, where this problem occurs?

Comment: So you're saying that the Java file still has the write commands in the correct order? That should result in the divs being written to the stream in that same order. How do you determine that the order has changed in the resulting HTML? Is there any component in between, e.g. a webserver, proxy etc.?

Comment: @Thomas  Ajax call response is html I can view in that and same got rendered as HTML on browser

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Jboss 7.2

Comment: What does your AJAX response actually return? A snipped of html or some sort of json that contains smaller html snippets? As you can see we're having difficulties understanding your problem so some more code, ideally a [mcve] would help.

Comment: @Thomas my application is an spring mvc app. which returns a JSP as view . JSP gets resolved in html by view resolver . Here ajax response is HTML snippet (ouput of a evaluated jsp), which needs to be painted under a master div